# How to add and remove a character from a cell to force a value change

Tags: google-sheets

I'm using a function to count the number of colored cells, but when they change color (not value), the spreadsheet doesn't recognize a value change and my formula doesn't update with the new number of colored cells.

To manually force an update, I have to add a character to that cell, then remove it, so that the sheet will recognize a value change and recount the number of colored cells. Is there a way to automate this and force the sheet to add and remove a character in order to force an update?

Hopefully, this is clear enough to be answerable.

Comment: can you share an example/code?

Comment: @oliver13 Here's a working link:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1X3mv4FNfamA67MQ2ta2WG7phLgRR7a2SOHYMzMuu-oI/edit?usp=docslist_api

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use onEdit function if there is any data update on the cells. But for your case, I have tested below scripts works good, but I am still confused it is the best practice of coding, because I could not find any other options to solve your question.

//Below function will count the number of cells with the specified background color

```
function countWhereBackgroundColorIs(color, rangeSpecification) {

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
var range = sheet.getRange(rangeSpecification);
var bgColors = range.getBackgrounds();
var k = 0;

  for (var i in bgColors) {
   for (var j in bgColors[i]) {
        if(bgColors[i][j] == color)
        k = k +1;
   }
 }
  return k;
}
```

//Below function will append a space" " on the cell A1 data and then remove the appended char. This is for updating the range. Make sure that at least a cell mentioned in above function countWhereBackgroundColorIs() is getting updated. Here Used 'A1'

```
function updateSheet()
{ 
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
  var cell = sheet.getRange("A1");
  var d = cell.getValue();
  cell.setValue(d+" ");
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  cell.setValue(d);
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();

}
```

//creating a time based trigger to execute the updateSheet() function for every one min. Minimum time is 1min. This trigger creation is a one time activity and this can be done in GUI also Resources>All your triggers.

```
function createTimeDrivenTriggers() {
ScriptApp.newTrigger('updateSheet')
   .timeBased()
   .everyMinutes(1)
   .create();

}
```